# Dictionary values with same key updates the last element in the for loop without using list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Frame list:

```
[
    [28580, 28585, 28590, 28595, 28600, 28605, 28610, 28615, 28620, 28625, 28630, 28635, 28640, 28645, 28650],
    [30045, 30050, 30055, 30060, 30065, 30070, 30075, 30080, 30085, 30090, 30095, 30100, 30105, 30105],
]
```

FPS: 30

```py
for j in range(0,len(finalframe_list)):
    clip_timestamp = int(finalframe_list[j][0]/self.fps)
    EliminationClip_record["event_timestamp"] = clip_timestamp
    clip_start = int(finalframe_list[j][0]/self.fps) - 10
    EliminationClip_record["start"] = clip_start
    clip_end = int(finalframe_list[j][-1]/self.fps) + 5
    EliminationClip_record["end"] = clip_end
```

Deque Dictionary :

```py
EliminationClip_record = {
    'start': 10,  
    'end': 5,  
    'event_timestamp': 5,
    'categories': ['xyz']
}
```

The output I am getting:

```py
deque([{'start': [942, 991], 'end': [960, 1008], 'event_timestamp': [952, 1001], 'categories': ['xyz']}])
```

The output I am expecting:

```
deque([{'start': [942], 'end': [960], 'event_timestamp': [952], 'categories': ['xyz']},{'start': [991], 'end': [1008], 'event_timestamp': [1001], 'categories': ['xyz']}])
```

It is updating the last element I am getting from the loop if I am updating within the loop. Can anybody suggest the way how I can get the desired output?

Comment: Hi, the code and input and output do not really correspond to each other. You state that the results of your calculation are fields (```'start': [942, 991], 'end': [960, 1008]```). But your given code cannot produce those results as for example ```EliminationClip_record["start"] = clip_start``` assigns an ```int``` and not an array.

Comment: Hi, Yes by mistake I have removed that part from the above code. The way you are saying is correct, it will give integer. Please help within the loop to update that value with the same key.

Comment: The code is incomplete to say something about the logic you are trying to achieve. Can you give more code that describes what and where you are trying to update what?

Comment: The output which I am getting is : deque([{'start': 991, 'end': 1008, 'event_timestamp': 1001, 'categories': ['xyz']}]) , These are the last elements in that for loop, Insead I need the output as : deque([{'start': 942, 'end': 960, 'event_timestamp': 952, 'categories': ['xyz']},{'start': 991, 'end': 1008, 'event_timestamp': 1001, 'categories': ['xyz']}])]) and deque is <class 'collections.deque'>